# How to query/fetch public feed elements in a community to which the user is not subscribed?

Tags: apex, soql, community, chatter, connect-api

#### Use Case

Display a list of all public questions and posts to a community user, regardless of whether or not that user is subscribed to the groups or users who posted.

#### What we've tried

SOQL query on feed items, then filtered after the SOQL for just that community because the where filter on networkId is broken (known issue).

#### The problem

We have so many feed items that the SOQL is now non-selective, which is breaking tests on the deploy, but not actually breaking anything in production. We are working on making it selective but that's not working.

#### How about the ConnectApi you say?

The ConnectApi has a getFeedElementsFromFeed method but the Company FeedType is not supported in Communities. That FeedType is the only FeedType that would return as broad of a scope to include questions and posts to which the user isn't following/subscribed but is still public and can see.

Aside from trying to make the SOQL selective, is there some other solution that I'm missing?